# Appending Parameters to ember data request?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have code which at one point runs this line:

```
var searchData = that.store.find("searchResult",{key: searchKey});
```

Essentially, I am trying to fetch all instances of the model searchResult.

My model code is as follows:

```
App.SearchResult = DS.Model.extend({
    searchResultID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityTypeID: DS.attr('number'),
    entityType: DS.attr('string'),
    searchText: DS.attr('string'),

});
```

This is pretty much all I have with respect to searcHRestult on the client side.

On the server side, I handle GET requests to the /searchResults route.

```
  this.resource('searchResults', {path: '/searchResults'});
```

The above is added to Ember Router.

I will however require to pass in a parameter {criteria: "user location" } through this route. The idea is that on the server side, my code will search this criteria parameter, then only run sql based on what criteria is needed. (i.e. if criteria = "user location", the code will run the sql related to "user" and "location").

However, on the server side, when I check the value of request.params, the value shows to be [].

So when I do:

```
var searchData = that.store.find("searchResult",{criteria: "user location"});
```

The criteria parameter never shows server side. Even with the first line of code I posted here, the searchKey never shows server side.

Am I missing something here? Do I have to do anything to enable parameter passing through to the server side ?

(I am using node.js as server).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, after an hour of testing, it seems that the parameter was being passed, and that it could be accessed. My test code was unfortunately placed.

So the correct way is definitely still:

```
that.store.find("searchResult",{key: value})
```

where 'key' is the parameter you want to pass, and value is the value for that parameter that you want to pass to the server side.

You would have to access these params through

```
request.query.key
```